# Application startup flags in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a way for a Windows Forms application to detect if any flags have been added to the command/shortcut used to launch it? Like if I wanted to go "app.exe /flag", can I get the "/flag" somewhere programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) to get an array of the arguments passed into your program.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to handle the `Application Startup` event where you'll have access to the `StartupEventArgs` which has a property called `CommandLine` which is a read-only collection of the command-line arguments.